# best methods of archiving data of a model in django

Tags: django

I have a Django model with name "modelA" with 10 million records, our team took a call to not show the first million records as that data would not be of any interest to our customers and data is very old. Now I have two options.

1. Don't archive any data, just add created_date param in the search query in such a way that first 1 million records get filtered out while searching against the modelA.
2. Archive the first 1 million records of modelA, so that we don't add created_date param in the search query.
   Can someone tell me please which option is more efficient.

Note: This model has references to other tables, so if I took a call to archive the data, I need to archive the referenced tables as well.

Comment: You will most likely get better performance (and use less disk space) if your database doesn't contain old records that are NEVER going to be used.  But the flipside is that the customer MIGHT need to access the records, then archiving them will make it awkward to do that.

Comment: Could you give more information ? For example, what database, cache system, infrastructure, etc. ? 
The options to "Archive" your datas depend on the technical environment of your project: adding a field "is_archived" to your model, partitioning the database, [partitionning using Django](https://awstip.com/turbocharge-your-django-application-mastering-database-partitioning-for-high-traffic-optimization-1c24031d34b8), Data Sharding, Cache system strategies or load balancing strategy.